# Android Studio Unknown host 'No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)'

Tags: android, android-studio, maven, build.gradle

Some information about the system:

1. I am using Android Studio Flamingo, 2022.2.1.
2. I am not behind a proxy.
3. I can visit the URL inside a browser.

Here are the dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

The error in Android Studio is:

> Unknown host 'No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

Steps that I have taken:

1. Invalidated Cache.
2. Set the proxy to auto.
3. Restarted Android Studio.
4. Restarted PC.